# Zip and AES encrypt in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, zip, aes

What's the easiest way to zip and encrypt a file with AES (128 or 256) in a Rails app, so that the zip archive can be opened with WinZip?

Requirements:

1. Zip archive can be opened by WinZip (so no 7-zip)
2. Zip archive is encrypted with AES-128 or AES-256 (which WinZip supports)

Gems:

1. Rubyzip: doesn't support encryption
2. Zipruby: supports only the traditional/legacy non-AES encryption which is significantly less secure.

Any advice on what I can do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are commercial products out of the question? [Chilkat Ruby Zip](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ruby-zip.asp) appears to support WinZip AES.  The [example code](http://www.example-code.com/ruby/ruby-create-encrypted-zip.asp) looks pretty temptingly easy.

There also appears to be [a Java library](https://code.google.com/p/winzipaes) available.  If you're running in JRuby...  Or if you feel like porting!

Comment: Thanks! Chilkat looks like it should work great. Excellent find!